# build rosjava failed

Tags: ros, build, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Recently i tried to build rosjava on a different computer with ROS Diamondback installed.

I checkout rosjava today with this command hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/
Then skipped the install step and go directly to this page (http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html), try to build rosjava on my computer. And I got following failure message:

```
> Building > :rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':rosjava_b:rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava
/home/nifti/Workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/MessageContextFactory.java:69: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method parseFromString(java.lang.String)
location: class org.ros.internal.message.PrimitiveFieldType
            primitiveFieldType.parseFromString(value));
                              ^
Note: /home/nifti/Workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/MessageImpl.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any idea what went wrong? Is it because I was building on ros dimondback?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32269/build-rosjava-failed/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-23**:
Currently, rosjava is only tested on Electric. However, that may not be the cause of your problem. Please follow the directions starting with: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html

It's difficult to diagnose build failures for non-standard configurations.

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-04-24**:
@damonkohler Did they forget the step in which you add export .../setup.sh to your .bashrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to be caused by a bug in the JDK: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6724345

I've pushed a workaround for this problem. Please update your checkout of rosjava and try again.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-04-24**:
It still fails for me with a new error: * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':rosjava_messages:generateSources'. > Command '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-25**:
Please run gradlew with --info or --stacktrace and open a new question.

**Comment by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on 2012-04-26**:
Thanks, it is successfully built now.

**Comment by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on 2013-03-24**:
What was the resolution to this problem?  I'm having the new issue listed here.